# Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipeline - no such property pipeline class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have created a basic declarative pipeline on Jenkins. When I run the build it spits outs the following error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:2)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
```

The Jenkins Server is set to default with the default plugins which are at the latest version. The Jenkinsfile is shown below

```
pipeline {
  agent any

   stages {
      stage('Sample Stage') {
          steps {
              sh '''
                ls
              '''
          }
      }
   }
}
```

It looks like the `pipeline` block is failing when Jenkins reads the Jenkinsfile which is rather confusing at the Jenkinsfile looks fine to me.

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178420/5151575

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Script Security Plugin 1.45 broke all the pipeline code

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you're running script in sandbox mode. Functions like pipeline are not published over there. It was out of the sandbox up to version 1.44 of the Script Security Plugin.

If you wish to run single branch pipeline - just unmark "Use Groovy Sandbox" at the bottom of your job settings page.
If you're using multibranch pipeline then possibly the only way for you is to downgrade the plugin.