# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline fails because it runs in Groovy Sandbox

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My Jenkins CI/CD build configuration was working and nothing changed until my last pull request and I need to get this working again.

The [Multibranch Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/12/03/pipeline-as-code-with-multibranch-workflows-in-jenkins/) is configured to run a `jenkinsfile` from BitBucket SCM but this is now failing with the following error;

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
```

[Script Security Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin) is installed and the In-process Script Approval has nothing listed to approve.

[Permissive Script Security Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/permissive-script-security) is installed and `jenkins.xml` is modified to include the `-Dpermissive-script-security.enabled=true` flag for running the `.war`.

These were implemented and working previously based on [How can I disable security checks for Jenkins pipeline builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933105)

As a test I created a Pipeline job which allows the Groovy Sandbox to be enabled and disabled. This was configured with the following cut down version of my pipeline script;

```
#!groovy

pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        VERSION = "${env.MAJOR_VERSION}.${env.MINOR_VERSION}"
        BUILD_LABEL = "MyProject ${env.VERSION} Build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY = "${WORKSPACE}\\src"
    }

    options {
        copyArtifactPermission('MyProject-Deploy')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }

    parameters {
        string (
            defaultValue: '3',
            description: 'MyProject Major Version',
            name : 'MAJOR_VERSION')
        string (
            defaultValue: '7',
            description: 'MyProject Minor Version',
            name : 'MINOR_VERSION')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Checkout Source') {
            steps {             
                echo('checkout scm')                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I enabled `Use Groovy Sandbox` and run the job I get the same error;

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
```

If I disable `Use Groovy Sandbox` the pipeline script completes successfully;

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Jenkins-Workspace\Pipeline-Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout Source)
[Pipeline] echo
checkout scm
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

- How do I ensure I have a clean Jenkins configuration?
- Should I attempt to downgrade Jenkins from v2.121.3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try downgrading the Script Security plugin from v1.45 to v1.44 and restarting Jenkins.

Just ran into this myself after updating plugins, although I'm not using the Permissive Script Security plugin.

Comment: What is the proper way for downgrading plugins? Jenkins doesn't allow me to downgrade **Script Security** because it is used for other plugins.

Comment: Thanks, also found [JENKINS-53421: Multibranch Declarative Pipeline No such property: pipeline](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53421) with the same advice.

Answer (score 3):

It's fixed in version 1.46 of the script-security plugin.

Comment: Confirming that upgrading to 1.46 fixed it for me.